# Append ACL resource under parent custom ACL resource from another module - "Could not create an acl object: Resource id already exists in the ACL"

Tags: magento2, module, permissions, acl

Using two modules: `Vendor_ModuleA` and `Vendor_ModuleB`, where `Vendor_ModuleA` will be a backend main menu/ACL module.

Other modules (in this example `Vendor_ModuleB`) should use the `ACL menu of Vendor_ModuleA` and *append a child tree entry into the navigation*.
The idea is that once this works, I can use resources for `Vendor_ModuleC` etc as well.

- **ACL for `ModuleA`:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::mainacl" title="Vendor Main ACL" sortOrder="1">
                    <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::mainmenu" title="Vendor Module A Main Menu" sortOrder="1" />
                    <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::systemconfigsettings" title="Vendor Module A Config Settings Access" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

- **ACL for `Vendor_ModuleB`** which I am attempting to use the resource parent tree (`Vendor_ModuleA`) and add a sub node inside.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::mainmenu">
                <resource id="Vendor_ModuleB::top_level" title="Module B Main Menu" sortOrder="1" />
            </resource>
            <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::systemconfigsettings">
                <resource id="Vendor_ModuleB::systemconfigsettings" title="Module B Config Settings" />
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

#### Error

This implementation results in the following error:

```
Could not create an acl object: Resource id 'Vendor_ModuleA::systemconfigsettings' 
already exists in the ACL
```

#### Issue

Most resources **append a sub-node into resource `Magento_Backend::admin`** as shown in ModuleA, but when I try to do the same **(append)** using the node `Vendor_ModuleA::systemconfigsettings` it now seems to think I am updating it, which is not the intention.

#### Question

How do I correctly configure ACL node to append as a child in seperate module/s?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it, although unfortunately the original idea to use is now slightly more complicated than I hoped (and less maintainable if the `ModuleA` ACL parent nodes changes).

##### Solution

> Use the full XML node references used in other modules, for every parent, otherwise Magento 2 currently interprets as you want to **override/replace** it instead of **appending to ACL node**

In the above example, to get `Vendor_ModuleB` to use the ACL nodes of `Vendor_ModuleA`, take the whole node structure of `Vendor_ModuleA`,

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::mainacl">
                    <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::mainmenu">
                        <resource id="Vendor_ModuleB::top_level" title="Module B Main Menu" sortOrder="1" />
                    </resource>
                    <resource id="Vendor_ModuleA::systemconfigsettings">
                        <resource id="Vendor_ModuleB::systemconfigsettings" title="Module B Config Settings" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl></config>
```

##### Further explanation

**The important thing to take note is that the XML is not handled the same way as in layouts.**

*ACL (at least in ~Magento 2.3) does not use the **layout** method of appending content into a `referenceContainer/referenceBlock`'*

So, when trying with the parent node to append to : `Vendor_ModuleA::systemconfigsettings` I assumed the `ACL` will use a similar loading mechanism as `layouts` in Magento 2, but it does not.

**All parent level nodes are required.**